# checkboxfor bind to model ajax postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get checkboxfor checked values through ajax postback in my controller but it is giving me false even if checkbox is checked in the view before clicking the button control.

my code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CivilSurveys(CivilSurveyViewModel modelData)
{
  try
  {
    var s = Request["SurveyAccepted"].Contains("true");
    if (modelData.SurveyAccepted)
      {
        modelData.SurveyAcceptedBy = int.Parse(Session["SessionUserId"].ToString());
        modelData.SiteDiagram = ViewBag.Image;
        modelData = (BAL.Surveys.GetCivilSurvey(modelData));
      }
      return View(modelData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
      return View();
    }
  }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCivilSurveys" }))
{
  <div class="ControlSet">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyAcceptedBy):
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SurveyAccepted, new { style = "margin-left:198px;"     })
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both; margin: 10px; padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden;">
    <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Create" style="float: right;" id="btnCreateCivilSurvey" />
    <input type="button" class="k-button" value="Update" id="btnEditCivilSurvey" style="float: right;" />
  </div>

<script>
  $("#btnCreateCivilSurvey").click(function() {
    if ($("#frmCivilSurveys").valid()) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CivilSurveys", "Civils")",
        data: JSON.stringify($('#frmCivilSurveys').serializeObject()),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
          if (msg.status == "1") {       }
            alert(msg.message);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $($("#frmCivilSurveys").validate().errorList[0].element).focus();
      }
      return false;
  });
</script>
```

it was becuse of hidden field that was autocreated while using checkboxfor.

I have resolved this issue by using input of type checkbox and mannually setting id's for them in foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SurveyTypeList)
{
  @Html.Label(item.Text)
  <input name="SurveyTypeList[@i].Text" type="hidden" value="@item.Text" />
  <input name="SurveyTypeList[@i].Value" type="hidden" value="@item.Value" />
 <input data-val="true" id="SurveyTypeList@(i)__IsSelected" name="SurveyTypeList[@i].IsSelected"          style="margin-right: 200px; float: right" type="checkbox" value="true" />
  <br /><br />
  i++;
  }
```

but this is not a perfect solution any ways, i need some more perfect solution for it

Comment: Whats `.serializeObject()` are you using a plugin? What happens if you just use `.serialize()`

Comment: I assume its [hongymagic jQuery.serializeObject](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject), in which case that probably the problem - it converts the values of the checkbox and its associated hidden input to an array which can't be bound to a `boolean`.

Comment: did you try my answer? does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("CivilSurveys", "Civils")",
    data: $('#frmCivilSurveys')),
    // dataType: "json", - Note you appear to be returning a view so this should be html
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
      ....
```

Key points

1. Use `.serialize()`, not `serializObject()`
2. Dont use `JSON.stringify`
3. Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Answer (score 0):

it was becuse of hidden field that was autocreated while using checkboxfor.

I have resolved this issue by using input of type checkbox and mannually setting id's for them in foreach loop like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.SurveyTypeList)
 {
  @Html.Label(item.Text)
  <input name="SurveyTypeList[@i].Text" type="hidden" value="@item.Text" />
   <input name="SurveyTypeList[@i].Value" type="hidden" value="@item.Value" />
  <input data-val="true" id="SurveyTypeList@(i)__IsSelected" name="SurveyTypeList[@i].IsSelected"      style="margin-right: 200px; float: right" type="checkbox" value="true" />
 <br /><br />
  i++;
  }
```

but this is not a perfect solution any ways, i need some more perfect solution for it

Comment: This is not necessary, and an awful way to render your html :). Refer my answer, you have a number of incorrect arguments in your ajax parameters